# Adding comma to number with jQuery, NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a function that when a user clicks "plus" or "minus" an input box is updated with an integer only I need to add the commas on each click manually.

If you click minus, it works at first but hitting it again renders it `NaN`. If I `console.log` this value it strips all characters after the first comma, this may not make much sense but take a look at the fiddle for a better example...

**JS**

```
function addCommas(intNum) {
  return (intNum + '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
}

$('#plus').on('click', function() {
    var value = $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val();
    $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val(addCommas(value));
 });

$('#minus').on('click', function() {
    var curVal = $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val();
    var val = 500;
    var newVal = curVal - val; 
    //newVal = newVal.replace(/,/g, "");

    alert( newVal );
    $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val(addCommas(newVal));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qhof0fq/1/

Comment: `"120,000"` is not a number. `console.log("120,000"-100)`

Comment: When you add a comma to a number, you are changing a number to string. And then you are trying to do a mathematical operation on a string. Hence Javascript throws "NaN": Not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `var curVal = $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val();` in minus function,

remove the commas and then parse it.

```
var curVal = $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val();
curVal = parseInt(curVal.replace(/,/g, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `,` is meaning that the value from the input cannot be coerced to an integer. You need to replace the commas before performing any mathematical operations: `.replace(/,/g, '')`

```js
function addCommas(intNum) {
  return (intNum + '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
}
$('#plus').on('click', function() {
  var value = $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val().replace(/,/g, '');
  $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val(addCommas(value));
});

$('#minus').on('click', function() {
  var curVal = $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val().replace(/,/g, '');
  var val = 500;
  var newVal = curVal - val;
  $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val(addCommas(newVal));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-slider property-value">
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div id='minus'>-</div>
    <div id='plus'>+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-value money">
    <input class="s-value number" type="tel" id="propertyValueSliderValue" value="120000" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use a `data` attribute to hold the value to use in the calculation while keeping the UI-friendly value separate. You can also use another data attribute to hold the `increment` to be added/removed from the value so that you can DRY up the click event handlers:

```js
function addCommas(intNum) {
  return (intNum + '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
}

var $propertySliderValue = $("#propertyValueSliderValue");

$('.inc').on('click', function() {
  var value = $propertySliderValue.data('value') + $(this).data('inc');
  $propertySliderValue.val(addCommas(value)).data('value', value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-slider property-value">
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div id='minus' class="inc" data-inc="-500">-</div>
    <div id='plus' class="inc" data-inc="500">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-value money">
    <input class="s-value number" type="tel" id="propertyValueSliderValue" data-value="120000" value="120,000" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when you get the value out the `#propertyValueSliderValue` it is a String:

change your code to this:

```
$('#minus').on('click', function() {
  var curVal = $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val();
  var parseVal = parseInt(curVal);
  var val = 500;
  var newVal = parseVal - val; 
  //newVal = newVal.replace(/,/g, "");

  alert( newVal );
  $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val(addCommas(newVal));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you read the value out of the input every time, and technically a number with the comma isn't a number in javascript.
What you can do is make a variable to keep track of the real number and only output the comma version to the user.

```js
var value = parseInt($("#propertyValueSliderValue").val());
var interval = 500;

function addCommas(intNum) {
  return (intNum + '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
}
 
$('#plus').on('click', function() {
    value += interval; 
    var commaNotatedVal = addCommas(value);
    $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val(commaNotatedVal);
 });
              
$('#minus').on('click', function() {
    value -= interval; 
    var commaNotatedVal = addCommas(value);
    $("#propertyValueSliderValue").val(commaNotatedVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-slider property-value">
      
       <div class="slider-wrap">
        <div id='minus'>-</div>
        <div id='plus'>+</div>
       </div>
       <div class="slider-value money">
        <input class="s-value number" type="tel" id="propertyValueSliderValue" value="120000" />
       </div>
         </div>
```